# What does the sigma mean in the notation $\sigma(X,X^*)$ (weak topology)?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, math-history

As a math student, I am also interested in the historical development of ideas in math.

I am studying Conway's Functional analysis book, and he uses the notation: $\sigma(X,X^*)$ for the weak topology on $X$ and $\sigma(X^*,X)$ for the weak-* topology on $X^*$. I think this sigma notation is pretty standard so it makes me wonder.

So my question: is the sigma notation $\sigma(X,X^*)$ or $\sigma(X^*,X)$ an artifact of an older math concept applied to functional analysis? Or is it simply just that, notation?

Comment: I think it comes from the fact that pointwise convergence was (is?) also called _simple_ convergence. And of course a Latin 's' corresponds to a Greek $\sigma$.

Comment: Or perhaps from the German *schwach* for weak. (Just a guess without having any evidence.)

Comment: Maybe from the German : [Schwache Topologie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwache_Topologie)

Comment: @DanielFischer, do you know a reference where simple convergence was mentioned? I have never encountered that term before.

Comment: Although I recall having read the term "simply convergent sequence" in works written in English, I don't remember where. However, in French [it's a standard term](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_simple). And since Schwartz and Grothendieck wrote in French, it would make sense if they derived the notation from it. However, I don't know who introduced the notation, and even if it was Schwartz or Grothendieck, there may have been a different reason, or it may have been just coincidence. It's just my guess.